# Can't Upload APK Due To Package Name Conflict Even Tho Its Not the same

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, ionic-framework

I am uploading two 'sister' apps to the Google Play store and am running into an issue with the second APK being given the following error message.

The apps for the purpose of this post are the following:

```
com.myapp.vendor -> APK Uploaded Successfully First
com.myapp.customer
```

I am using `Cordova/Ionic` also.

[image]

The first APK I uploaded had the name `com.myapp.vendor` and everything worked fine and the APK is uploaded.

I have checkedthe `config.xml` and the `AndroidManifest.xml` and they look like the following:

The `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="0.0.1" 
          package="com.myapp.customer"            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</manifest>
```

and the `config.xml` looks like the following:

```
<widget id="com.myapp.customer" 
        version="0.0.1"  
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"         xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
   <name>MyApp</name>
   <description>
    MyApp
   </description>
</widget>
```

I have blasted the `platforms/android` directory and ran through the process several times and I still get this error. Is there some other magic that `Cordova` or `Ionic` is doing that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot and I had one of my commands pointing at the other APK scripts.

For anybody running into this issue, TRIPLE check your stuff is right. I swore repeatedly that I had it correct, and it was a simple typo...